# Trying to unzip the file but it's giving invalid zip file which overlapped components (possible zip bomp)

Tags: zip

Same zip file can be unzipped with the same command on jump node but not on data nodes and the version is same in all the nodes

Comment: have you check the hash of all zip files?

Comment: How about more info? What are these nodes running? Same as the jump node? Is the zip file compressed with unix zip or gzip or what? How explicitly are you transferring the file to the other nodes? What is the precise error message?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious explanation is that the copies of the file on the data nodes have different contents than the file on the jump node.  Have you used a command like `md5sum filename` to find out if the file data is the same on all nodes?